# Deploying website in azure

Tags: azure, web-config, umbraco

I am trying to deploy a website in azure Ive checked the web.config  and double check my connection string even custom error set to Off and adding existingResponse="PassThrough" under system.webServer the error still showing "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.". 
Is it a security problem in azure?

Comment: have you checked the logs on your azure website?

Comment: Hello JunT,

 I'm sorry, I have no control in my azure. I uploaded my website using FTP. I have logs folder in my website but there is no error. :(